# Common C++ Architecture

Tags: c++, oop, architecture, stl

I've been programming C++ and Java for quite a while now and have some questions about common C++ architecure.

When I program in Java I try to mimic the standard library, that is using interfaces such as Iterable and Serializable and having similar naming conventions and functionality. With C++ however, I hesitate when trying to mimic the STL conventions (with the exception of iterators).

I've boiled it down to the following questions (are the following common convention to implement):

- Allocators
- Interfaces (classes with only pure virtual methods)
- Templates instead of abstract base classes
- Restricting exception throwing...
- ... or having a class optionally throw exceptions (such as in std streams)
- Using typedefs for, more or less, obvious types (reference_type, pointer_type, value_type, ...)

Or is the std of C++ not worth mimicing at all?

Thank you for your opinions / answeres!

Comment: Hm. This is difficult to answer in a meaningful way. You are really asking six distinct big questions; "Why does the STL use <x>", for x in <all your points>. This is too much. I am voting to close this question because of its overly broad scope. Try instead asking about one of them. Something like "Why does the STL use allocators? I have never used them, and I am wondering why they are there. Should I write my own classes to be parameterized by allocators?", for example.

Comment: Well if I seperate them into more questions, they would all be like: 
Is it common convention to use allocators for custom containters?
Is it common convention to use interfaces? And so on... For my own projects I prefer to follow good practice, then the jump from my projects to someone else's is smaller. So really what I would like to know is, "Is it good practice to follow STL-style coding?".

Answer (score 1):

The more I've used C++, the less fond I am of mimicking the best of libraries I find.  The problem comes in when we get a junior developer on the team.  They'll understand the basics, but not the subtleties of the language.  They may know how to create a map or list using the template syntax, but be unable to understand it when it's applied to another object.  The added complexities of debugging and doing code read-throughs also take valuable time away from solving problems or advancing your product.

I have grown to lean towards using the most basic features of the language, which typically leaves the code in a more naturally readable state.  I've regretted deviations from this path when I go back 8-12 months later to hunt down an obscure bug with the code.

Java, on the other hand, has more simplistic library implementations that is very well understood by more junior Java developers.  I do find that junior Java developers tend to have a greater understanding of the language then junior C++ developers.  The being said, C++ developers have more opportunity to become truly competent owing to the lower level of thought needed to become an intermediate C++ programmer.

Comment: I don’t buy “the added complexity”. As far as I’m concerned, the standard library is quite excellent in reducing complexity. True, *writing* easy-to-use general-purpose libraries is hard, but then it always is. Leaving out those features *increases* the complexity of client code, quite substantially.

Comment: Sounds like they're doing a better job teaching Java than C++. Also, if you have a lot of junior developers, then you'll have to dumb things down in any language. I've hit this problem in Python and C, too. You'd be surprised, or maybe you wouldn't, how many junior devs don't understand why you'd want a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: So... screw C++ standard style, make my own framework style?

Answer (score 1):

It greatly depends on your project. The general advice seems to be: Don't bother having a concrete standard for C++.

E.g. with typedefs there are multiple opinions both "for" and "against".

The reason why a concrete coding style for C++ is less important in C++ is because the language does not provide the ways to enforce and check those styles.
I.e. the grammar isn't easily parsable and therefore there are pretty much no tools to meaningfully style-check / refactor C++ code.
Which means that the weight of the style-check falls on the programmer's shoulders. I.e. it makes less sense to enfore style guides, because then much of the time saved by them is wasted in manual style checks.

So just use whatever your project / company uses or decides to use.

Here are my personal preferences:

**Allocators:** No opinion. If you need a custom allocator, chances are you'll know better than me what to do with it.
**Interfaces:**  If you're doing any performance-sensitive work - don't. They make things noticeably slower in a realtime application. Both abstract virtual classes and the pImpl pattern.
**Templates instead of abstract base classes:** It depends. But the general opinion seems to be that templates should be used for container-like functionality and a few other simple cases. Otherwise, it's a decent pattern. Debugging these is still a serious pain and will be in the next few years.
**Restricting exception throwing:** Yeah, do that. Try not to use exceptions, because believe it or not, in 2012 they are still not universally supported.
**Using typedefs:**: Just try to use c++11's std::auto. Otherwise, they kind of make your life harder because they're halfway to #define macros. I'd personally use an IDE (or Vim) to ease the typing stress of longs names and write the long names.

Comment: Templates have a lot of power that's hard to explain. Alexandrescu made a good attempt with *Modern C++ Design*.

Comment: Re: Restricting exception throwing - Do you have any examples of this? I've never seen a somewhat recent compiler that doesn't, even in the embedded space.

Comment: What I mean by restricting exception throwing is simply using the throw(...) keyword at (most or all) methods.

Comment: @CollinHockey yes, the XBoX compiler does not support exceptions. When talking about C++, a lot of it is in gamedev code, so that's no small thing.